# Use of Underscore in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Why this works?

```
def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = { forall(s, !p(_)) }
```

And this doesn't?

```
def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = { forall(s, !p()) }
```

Where `forall` is a function, and `p` is predicate.

Comment: p takes a parameter.  In one case you are passing a parameter and in the other you are not passing a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

The call to the predicate is expecting a parameter to be passed, so you can't call it without passing anything (which is what `p()` is doing).

The underscore is kind of Scala short-hand for "the current value", where that value is the Int to be passed to p. If we were to explicitly label that Int as `i`, then this de-sugars to:

```
{ forall(s, (i: Int) => !p(i)) }
```